# IBM for i / RPG: How to compile a module and create a service program with one call in IBM Rational Developer for i (RDi)

Tags: rpgle, rpg, rational-developer-for-i

How to avoid having to use the Compile menu of RDi 2 times in a row - to create first a SQL RPGLE module and then to create the service program associated?

Comment: Note that *SRVPGM are designed to be made up of multiple modules.  Having 1 module per service program means you lose out on one level of privacy; procedures (or variables) exported from a module but not the service program.  Those are only usable by other modules in the service program.   I usually think of them as "protected" vs. just having "private" and "public".

Comment: @Charles You're absolutely right! However, as usual, there are always trades off between theory (possibilities/"proper way") and pragmatisme (efficiency/maintainability/documentation)...
Without the assistance of a third part tool, I prefer a one-to-one relationship to avoid all complexity at maintenance time!

Comment: Just create a program that creates your service programs. That way you don't have to remember all that much, and you can create the service program easily enough. Naming conventions help as well, and no third party tool is required to manage the minimal complexity.

Answer (score -1):

For that, you create first a CL Program (let's name it CRTSRVPRG) like this:

```
         PGM        PARM(&LIBRARY &SOURCE &NAME &HASITFCHG)

         DCL        VAR(&LIBRARY) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)
         DCL        VAR(&SOURCE)  TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)
         DCL        VAR(&NAME)    TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(10)
         DCL        VAR(&HASITFCHG)    TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)


         CRTSQLRPGI OBJ(&LIBRARY/&NAME) SRCFILE(&LIBRARY/&SOURCE) SRCMBR(&NAME) REPLACE(*YES) OBJTYPE(*MODULE) RPGPPOPT(*LVL2) DBGVIEW(*SOURCE) OPTION(*EVENTF)

         IF         COND(&HASITFCHG = 'Y') THEN(DO)
            CRTSRVPGM  SRVPGM(&LIBRARY/&NAME) MODULE(&LIBRARY/&NAME) EXPORT(*ALL) SRCFILE(&LIBRARY/&SOURCE)
            RTVBNDSRC  SRVPGM(&LIBRARY/&NAME) SRCFILE(&LIBRARY/QSRVSRC)
            CHGPFM     FILE(&LIBRARY/QSRVSRC) MBR(&NAME) SRCTYPE(BND)
         ENDDO

         ELSE       CRTSRVPGM  SRVPGM(&LIBRARY/&NAME) MODULE(&LIBRARY/&NAME) EXPORT(*SRCFILE) SRCFILE(&LIBRARY/QSRVSRC) SRCMBR(&NAME)

         ENDPGM
```

Then in the menu Compile / Compile / Work With Compile Command…, you add the following 2 new commands:

1. "New service program or change in the interface"

   CALL PGM([your library]/CRTSRVPRG) PARM(&L &F &N 'Y') /* OPTION(*EVENTF) SRCMBR(&N) */
2. "Recompile service program"

   CALL PGM([your library]/CRTSRVPRG) PARM(&L &F &N 'N') /* OPTION(*EVENTF) SRCMBR(&N) */

Tipp: you can use the button "Run compile command without prompting" from the toolbar to execute the last command, without having to use the menu.

The addition in the command of

```
/* OPTION(*EVENTF) SRCMBR(&N) */
```

gives you the feedback for the module compilation in the Tab "Error List".
Unfortunately, there is no feedback for the creation of the Service Program. For that, you'll have to look into the Tab "Commands Log"...

Comment: `EXPORT(*ALL)` is a bad idea, you should always use binder source when creating *SRVPGM objects.

Comment: @Charles Thank you for your comment. The reason I'm using EXPORT (*ALL) is because I want all the bindings to be declared within my code (using ctl-opt bnddir('[Lib name]/[File]');) and not at compile time, to keep the compile command as generic as possible!

Comment: Binder source is completely different than a binding directory.  Without binder source, everytime you change a *SRVPGM you have to re-bind everything that uses that *SRVPGM.

Comment: To expand on what Charles said, the BNDDIR keyword in the CTL-OPT tells the binder where to find the procedures that your modules need. The EXPORT parameter on the CRTSRVPGM tells the binder how to create the signature for your new service program.

Your CL program should have another parameter for the binder source. Or it could assume that the binder source is in QSRVSRC in the same library as the other source with the same member name as the service program, EXPORT(*SRCFILE) SRCFILE(&LIBRARY/QSRVSRC) SRCMBR(&NAME).

Comment: If you try to make things easier by just using EXPORT(*ALL), you'll actually make things a zillion times more difficult when you start running into the problems created by using EXPORT(*ALL).

Comment: If you use EXPORT(*ALL) your procedures are exported in alphabetical order. Normally you should only add procedures to the end of the binder source so that you don't have to recompile the world every time you add a procedure to the service program. By using Export all, that al goes out the window, and you will always have to recompile everything that uses the service program every time you add something to it.

Comment: And your binder source should start with `STRPGMEXP  SIGNATURE("XXXXXXX v1.0")`  where XXXXXXX is the service program name. Never remove exports, and only ever add exports to the end of the list. Only change the signature when you want to recompile everything that references the service program.